# tkinter transform function to multi instance of class

Tags: python, function, class, animation, tkinter

I´m quite new to python and would like to call this function within a class several times as parallel operations. When I do so, I keep overwriting `self.Satellit` with each call. How can I create multiple instances of this? Is there another way of not overwriting `self.Satellit`? Here is the shortened code, the TKinter relevant code is marked (###):

```
def realtime_Position(self,i):
                
        def Aktualisierung():
            try:
                self.Object.get_tk_widget().pack_forget()
            except AttributeError: 
                pass
            
            figure = plt.Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100, tight_layout=True)
            ax1 = figure.add_subplot(111)
            self.Object = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=self.Satellit)
            self.Object.get_tk_widget().pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

            ax1.set_title(i+ " realtime Chart")
            figure.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
### HERE-
            self.Satellit.after(realtime_Abrufrate_1, Aktualisierung)

        self.Satellit = tk.Toplevel(root, bd = 5, relief = GROOVE)
        self.Satellit.iconbitmap('bull_trend.ico')
        self.Satellit.title(i+" Realtime")
### -TO HERE
        
        figure = plt.Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100, tight_layout=True)
        ax1 = figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.Object = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=self.Satellit)
        self.Object.get_tk_widget().pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
        
### AND HERE-
        self.Satellit.after(realtime_Abrufrate_1, Aktualisierung) 
### -TO HERE
```

Comment: Have you tried making `self.Satellit` a list? Or, make `Aktualisierung` a class?

Comment: Dear Bryan, thank you again. No I didn´t. How can I do this? Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Will `self.Satellit` and `self.Object` be used outside this function? If not, just change them to local variables.

Comment: And if you followed acw`s solution you could combine it with the idea of Bryan to add these in list to access them.

Comment: please post an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you need help